# Can you have two tables in Visual studio 2008 report (in the report control) and how

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, reporting

Can you have two tables in Visual studio 2008 report (in the report control) and how is that done?

I have a database with multiple tables and when I go to add a report control and then add a report it appears to only allow me to have one of the tables. I see all the tables in my data GUI but when I select properties on the report it only has the one table as the data.

Where do I need to look to add the entire table as valid data or can you not do that?

EDIT:

I am still not sure how to do this with the control.
If you use the reporting service app, it has a wizard that takes a query as an input. With that query I get the data I need.

Comment: Do you want something like a SubReport? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159837.aspx

Comment: Not sure, this is all new to me. 

I will give you an example of what I am doing and maybe you can tell me.

Say I have two tables (maybe more in database but I only care about these two). One table is all my employees and another table is all of the customers. 

Then I want to run a report of which employee is assigned to which customer (the id for employee is a foreign key for customer).

I don't see how I can create this report with out access to both tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went on to try the reporting services.

I think the answer is to create a query that returns the data needed from more than one table.

Answer (score 1):

I am also dealing with kind of same scenario, where one of my crystal report in VS2008 is using 2 tables. I created a DataSet for this report (Right click on project and select Add New and select DataSet), and created 2 tables in dataset; and then using this dataset to create my report. When you go to Database expert of the report, it shows option for ADO.NET DataSets, select the dataset you created (with multiple tables). It should show all the tables in dataset for selection.

In my scenario I am populating data into DataTables on run time. So first I put data into tables (creating C# class object DataTable), and then insert these datatables into dataset and putting DataSet as report's DataSource.

I hope it will be helpful.

Cheers.